# Datatable : Cannot search the dataTable from search field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I know there is lots of solution available for my problem, But somehow I am doing something wrong in my situation, I am very newbie for the web development. So can't be able to fix this solution. I am parsing the datatable from the server, but its not happening, If I am not wrong then when user start typing then some query param should pass to the server side, Even I checked that but its not happening in result its returning the whole json.

What I have done is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
          serverSide: true,
          "filter": true,  
          processing: true,
          "paging": true,
          "ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
            $.get('http://localhost:8080/rural/ajax/all_users.php', {
                limit: data.length,
                offset: data.start,
                }, function(res) {
                  var json = JSON.parse(res);
                    callback({
                        recordsTotal: json.count,
                        recordsFiltered: json.count,
                        data: json.results
                    });
              });
          },
          "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "contact_no" },
            { "data": "address" },
            { "data": "email_id" },
            { "data": "sensor_count" },
            { "data": "registered_on" },
            { "data": "action"}
          ]
        });
    });
```

When I have searched the query which is parsed in the server I can see its only passing the limit and offset. Please find the screenshot below :

[image: Screenshot of the query param]

So my question is how to pass the query param to the server side. so that I can filter the search across my DB. Any solution will be great help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
$("inputNamehere").on('keyup', function() {
    table.columns([index number(0,1)]).search($(this).val()).draw();
});`